# Interrupting more SwingWorkers at once

Tags: swingworker

So I am currently running 3 SwingWorkers from Executer:

1. Collect info from website using htmlunit and if something new is added then it shows in table in GUI and sends to connected clients
2. Waits for clients connections and if clients connect then it adds him to table of connected client
3. Checks every 10s by sending data to client if he is still active and updates table of connected clients according to this

The main problem is if one of SwingWorkers is interrupted (for example by some exception or error) and ends other 2 should end too as they would be pointless running alone.

I added this part of code to every SwingWorker done() function:

```
synchronized(lock)
{
   try{
       for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
            try{
                if (threads.get(i)!=null && threads.get(i)!=this){

                      threads.get(i).cancel(true);

                }
            } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException ex) {

            }
          }
   } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException ex) {

   }
}
```

Where threads is arraylist of swingworkers I should end at once

This solution is working for me ,but I would like to know if there is any other better solution?

Answer (score 0):

how about making a global boolean variable and use it as a flag in all SwingWorkers?

when that flag is `false`, then each SwingWorker will exit the process.. (usually that's how you end threads..)

**EDIT**:
this is what I meant.. not pretty but might work for your need..

```
protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
    publish("Start..");
    setProgress(1);

    if(!flag) return -1;
    publish("Done more work..");
    setProgress(10);

    if(!flag) return -1;
    publish("Done more work again..");
    setProgress(30);

    // Completed
    publish("Completed..");
    setProgress(100);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Well do you mean that I add some global variable to every doInBackground method and check for it in every step?